# Running .bin executable using ansible in linux

Tags: ansible

I am very new to ansible. I am able to create ansible scripts to install rpm and deb packages. However I am not finding any example to run and install .bin files
The idea is to trigger the installation of .bin file which is sitting on the local download folder.

Is that possible?
i've tried like this

```
- file: path=$HOME/Downloads/Xplorer-6.0.1-linux-installer.bin state=touch mode="u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx"

- expect:
    command: $HOME/Downloads/Xplorer-6.0.1-linux-installer.bin
    responses: 
      Question: Do you accept this license? [y/n]
        - response: y
```

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: updated my question with what I;ve tried.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the '[script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html)' module. It works like:

`- script: /some/local/bin_file.bin --some-arguments 1234 creates=/the/created/file.txt`

The creates argument is optional and only used if you need to guarantee *idempotence*.

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question. I'll try your method